# onBrowserUpdateAvailable vs onRestartRequired: How should an app deal with out of date Browser blocking app updates?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've found users are not getting updates to my Chrome App because they keep the app open, and let their browser get out of date (i.e. the hamburger icon is red for a prolonged period).

Empirically it seems the `chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable` event is not triggered when the browser itself is out of date.

At a minimum I'd like to display an in-App warning UI to tell the user the need to restart the browser to get updates (and eventually, block usage of the app altogether until updated).  It *seems* like `chrome.runtime.onBrowserUpdateAvailable` was intended exactly for this, however that event is marked as long deprecated, but the replacement isn't good for this  use case: chrome.runtime.onRestartRequired is only supported  on Chrome OS, for kiosk apps.

The relevant bugs, http://crbug.com/177029 and http://crbug.com/242983  didn't really explain if onBrowserUpdateAvailable ever worked on non-ChromeOS versions, and if so, why it made sense to deprecate it without replacement on those other OSes.

Am I going about this all wrong? should I just use the deprecated event? Do people know that event works reliably for this scenario across OSes?

*(I haven't experimented with the APIs in great depth, and only have the documentation to go on, as browser updates are sufficiently infrequent it's going to be a very long experiment to run, and API behavior may change across versions during that experiment anyway).*

Answer (score 0):

If you need users to update to your latest client in order to work with your non-backward-compatible server, then you have complete control over the situation: detect the client mismatch and cease functioning (with a message explaining why) until the user restarts Chrome and gets your updated app.*

But if you're merely annoyed as a matter of hygienics that users aren't updating, it's hard to justify such a drastic approach. Moreover, by definition you're dealing with users who for some reason just plain don't care about updating anything, which is why they've been ignoring the red hamburger for who-knows how long. If this is the case, then adding yet another noisy notification probably isn't going to cure their behavior. Cue your personal equivalent of Serenity Prayer here.

*Side note: I'm surprised that app updates would be stalled because of lack of browser updates. Are you sure your app wasn't updated to specify a `minimum_chrome_version`? That case would be understandable, because we wouldn't want to update a Chrome App to a version known to be incompatible with the current browser.

Comment: Some clarifications:
- I need auto-update as the Chrome App is talking to peripheral  embedded devices (via USB and BLE). They have auto-updating firmware, and the policy we'd taken was that the FW assumes the chrome app is always latest version to keep the compat burden out of FW.
- Our app never set a minimum_chrome_version, so I'm sure it wasn't that.

Comment: I see. So the app is actually the more nimble of the two endpoints in the communication. Let me noodle on that a bit.